# jQuery parents then locate a div to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so i've got this .parents() function that goes outside to a located class/id. In my case, (.wrapper).

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="hide">Hide Class</div>
<div class="boxClass></div>
</div>
```

I've got a list of these div's on a single page, so, if i click the "Hide Class" text, everything would fadeout, since everything in the list, has the same class name. Now, back to my question. I use .parents() to locate (.wrapper) (i know this can be done with (.parent)). But how can i use .parents to go back and then select (fadeOut) a class inside it? EX, boxClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, they're siblings, so just use the [`siblings()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method  in the handler.

```
$(this).siblings('.boxClass').fadeOut();
```

---

Or if they're not actually siblings, use the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method then the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.boxClass').fadeOut();
```

---

Inside a handler `this` represents the element that invoked the handler. As such, it is a direct reference to the specific `.hide` element that was clicked.

Comment: @Henrikz: You're welcome. I fixed the reference to the `.hide()` method. Should have been `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('.hide').parents().children('.boxClass').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

.children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree.  Use find():

```
$('.hide').parents().find('.boxClass').fadeOut();
```